# Setting up website with separate app in virtual directory Asp.Net Forms authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, forms-authentication

I have an Asp.net MVC Website using Forms authentication.

The site is hosted in IIS using Forms Auth and works fine.

Due to a number of reasons, I want to know if it is possible to do the following:

I want to create a Virtual Directory underneath the main website, a separate application, and secure it using Forms Authentication as well.

The main site, and the site in the child Virtual Directory will be separate applications, and the Forms Auth will be completely independent of each other, and using different databases.

Is it possible to set up in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forms authentication works by using cookies. So as long as you provide different authentication cookie names for both sites they will be independent.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".Auth1" />
</authentication>
```

But the problem AFAIK is that the `<authentication mode="Forms">` tag cannot be redefined in sub web.config files.

Comment: I've got it nearly working actually using the name attribute. If I get it working I'll post an answer. thanks Darin.